# How to write bulleted list in pdf using itext jar but item should not in next line

Tags: itext

Below is the code I have searched from net. this code is printing the each list item in next line but I don't want like that.

Below is expected output I want to write in pdf:

```
List orderedList = new List(List.ORDERED);
orderedList.add(new ListItem("Item 1"));
orderedList.add(new ListItem("Item 2"));
orderedList.add(new ListItem("Item 3"));
```

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: I want each each item should be in same line

Comment: How about putting everything on a line with bullets in between? Or do you expect some special formatting?

Comment: Below is expected output.
● Insurancesystem ● Agent ● Agency ● AgentEnrollment ● AgentSettings ● Appointment

Comment: We hear you @MukeshSingh, but why are you using `List` if you don't need a list? All you need is a `Paragraph` with items that are preceded by bullets.

Comment: Yupe what's what i want but i don't know that.
Can you tell me the code for expected output.

Comment: My PC is acting strange (everything is very slow), but as soon as he's running normally again, I'll make you an example.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter

import javax.swing.text.Document

public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] ITEMS = ["Insurance system", "Agent", "Agency", "Agent Enrollment", "Agent Settings",
        "Appointment", "Continuing Education", "Hierarchy", "Recruiting", "Contract",
        "Message", "Correspondence", "Licensing", "Party"];
    com.lowagie.text.Document document = new com.lowagie.text.Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("List1.pdf"));
    Font zapfdingbats = new Font();
    Font font = new Font();
    Chunk bullet = new Chunk("\u2022", zapfdingbats);
    document.open();
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Items can be split if they don't fit at the end: ", font);
    for (String item: ITEMS) {
        p.add(bullet);
        p.add(new Phrase(" " + item + " ", font));
    }
    document.add(p);
    document.close();

}
```

Comment: You are using **my name** (I am Bruno **Lowagie**) in your code. That is wrong! It means that you are using a version of iText that is obsolete, unsupported,... Your customer should not accept your code [for these reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially).

Comment: Ugh... you initially accepted my answer because it was correct and it helped you. Why did you "unaccept" my answer in favor of your own answer that doesn't add anything new?

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need a `List`, you just need a sequence of bulleted items in a `Paragraph`.

I've created a proof of concept that shows you three ways of achieving this: good, better, and best:

[image]

Suppose that I have these items:

```
public static final String[] ITEMS = {
    "Insurance system", "Agent", "Agency", "Agent Enrollment", "Agent Settings",
    "Appointment", "Continuing Education", "Hierarchy", "Recruiting", "Contract",
    "Message", "Correspondence", "Licensing", "Party"
};
```

And that I have the following fonts and chunk:

```
Font zapfdingbats = new Font(FontFamily.ZAPFDINGBATS, 8);
Font font = new Font();
Chunk bullet = new Chunk(String.valueOf((char) 108), zapfdingbats);
```

Then the "good" example looks like this:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Items can be split if they don't fit at the end: ", font);
for (String item: ITEMS) {
    p.add(bullet);
    p.add(new Phrase(" " + item + " ", font));
}
document.add(p);
```

I create a `Paragraph`, I loop over all the items, and I add a bullet, a space character, the item and a space character to the paragraph as many times as there are items.

As you can see, there might be a problem with "Agent Enrollment". Because of the space character between "Agent" and "Enrollment", the item is split in two. This may be acceptable for you, but let's assume it isn't.

This leads us to the better solution:

```
p = new Paragraph("Items can't be split if they don't fit at the end: ", font);
for (String item: ITEMS) {
    p.add(bullet);
    p.add(new Phrase("\u00a0" + item.replace(' ', '\u00a0') + " ", font));
}
document.add(p);
```

Instead of ordinary spaces, we now introduce *non-breaking spaces* (`/u00a0`). This is already better, because items with spaces such as "Agent Enrollment" are no longer split. Unfortunately, we are dealing with different chunks for the bullet and the item, so it can happen that the bullet and its item are split anyway. That leads to the best solution:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font f = new Font(bf, 12);
p = new Paragraph("Items can't be split if they don't fit at the end: ", f);
for (String item: ITEMS) {
    p.add(new Phrase("\u2022\u00a0" + item.replace(' ', '\u00a0') + " ", f));
}
```

Instead of using a font that knows how to draw a bullet (Zapfdingbats) and a font that doesn't know how to draw a bullet (Helvetica), we use a font that can draw both (Arial). In my case, `arial.ttf` can be found in my `c:/windows/fonts` directory.

I still use `\u0060` to avoid that the items are split, but I also introduce `\u2022` which is the UNICODE value of the bullet stored in Arial.

For the full source code, see [Bullets](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/Bullets). For the resulting PDF, see [bullets.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/bullets.pdf)

Comment: Output ou your code is:
Items can be split if they don't fit at the end: l Insurance system l Agent l Agency l Agent
Enrollment l Agent Settings l Appointment l Continuing Educ

It is not printing bullect symbal

Comment: My screen shot proves you wrong. I'll post the full source code and the PDF online in a moment. I am pretty sure that you're not using the correct font!

Comment: I've added proof that what you claim is not true: http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/bullets.pdf (As you can see, this is a link to the *official* iText site!)

Comment: Please share your complete source code.
However Its working now with below changes. 
Chunk bullet = new Chunk("\u2022", zapfdingbats);

Comment: @MukeshSingh I just did!